# Prove that if $z$ is uni modular then $\frac{1+z}{1 + \bar z}$ is equal to $z$.

Tags: complex-numbers

The expression can be written as 
$$\frac{1+z}{\overline {1+z}}$$

Since $z \cdot \overline z=|z|^2$
$$\overline{1+z}= \frac{1}{1+z}$$
As $|z|=1$

So it will become $(1+z)^2$

But the answer is $z$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can write $\overline{1 + z}$ *via* the $LaTeX$ "\$\overline{1 + z}\$"; note we use "\overline" and not "\bar". (which giives a short bar and won't go over all of $1 + z$).  Don't forget the braces.  Cheers!

Comment: Suggested an edit to fix the LaTeX formatting: using \bar puts a fixed-width bar over the character; using \overline puts a bar that extends to cover the whole length of the expression.

Comment: Got it! Will keep that in mind

Comment: "then the $\frac{1 + z}{\overline{1 + z}}$  . . . .is what?  I guess you mean it is also unimodular, but if complete sentences work for former President Obama, they will for you. ;)  Cheers! . .

Comment: Fixed it. Cheers!

Comment: Great!  Thanks for responding.  Good edits!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asserting that if $z\cdot \overline z=1$ then $(1+\overline z)(1+z)=1,$ too. That is not true. A simple case is $z=1.$

Being unimodular means $z\cdot \overline{z}=1.$ Then $\overline z = z^{-1}.$

So $$\frac{1+z}{1+\overline{z}}=\frac{1+z}{1+z^{-1}}=\frac{1+z}{1+z^{-1}}\cdot \frac z z=\frac{z(1+z)}{z+1}=z$$

Note, the left side is not defined in the case $z=-1.$

Answer (score 1):

Assume $z=e^{i\theta}$ therefore

$$\frac{1+z}{1+\bar z}=\frac{1+e^{i\theta}}{1+e^{-i\theta}}=\frac{e^{i\theta}(1+e^{i\theta})}{e^{i\theta}(1+e^{-i\theta})}=\frac{e^{i\theta}(1+e^{i\theta})}{e^{i\theta}+1}=e^{i\theta}$$

which is valid for $z\neq -1$.

Comment: So removing the modulus gives us z? I am not really sure

Comment: @Aditya We have shown that if $|z|=1$ then also $\left|\frac{1+z}{1 + \bar z}\right|=1$. Are you looking for something different?

Comment: But  we don't have that $|w|^2=1$.

Comment: @user I understood your method, but is it possible to complete what I did to achieve $z$ as the answer?

Comment: Forget it, mine was wrong. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Note that for *any*

$\chi \in \Bbb C \tag 1$

we have

$\vert \chi \vert = \vert \bar \chi \vert; \tag 2$

this is easily seen by writing

$\chi = a + bi; \tag 3$

then

$\bar \chi = a - bi; \tag 4$

thus,

$\vert \chi \vert = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = \vert \bar \chi \vert; \tag 5$

or, if one prefers polars,

$\chi = re^{i\theta}, \; \bar \chi = re^{-i\theta}, \tag 6$

and so

$\vert \chi \vert = \vert re^{i\theta} \vert = r \vert e^{i\theta} \vert = r = r \vert e^{-i\theta} \vert = \vert re^{-i\theta} \vert = \vert \bar \chi \vert; \tag 7$

so if

$\chi \ne 0, \tag 8$

$\left \vert \dfrac{\chi}{\bar \chi} \right \vert = \dfrac{\vert \chi \vert}{\vert \bar \chi \vert} = 1; \tag 8$

we finish off by setting

$\chi = 1 + z \tag 9$

(assuming of course $z \ne -1$), whence

$\bar \chi = \overline{1 + z} = 1 + \bar z, \tag{10}$

whence

$\left \vert \dfrac{1 + z}{{1 + \bar z}} \right \vert = \left \vert \dfrac{1 + z}{\overline{1 + z}} \right \vert = 1.  \tag{11}$

Finally, if we write

$1 + z = re^{i\theta}, \tag{12}$

we find

$1 + \bar z = \overline{1 + z} = re^{-i\theta}, \tag{13}$

and so

$\left \vert \dfrac{1 + z}{\overline{1 + z}} \right \vert = \left \vert \dfrac{re^{i\theta}}{re^{-i\theta}} \right \vert = \vert e^{2i\theta} \vert = 1. \tag{14}$

With

$\vert z \vert = 1, \tag{15}$

$z = e^{i\theta}, \; \bar z = e^{-i\theta}, \tag{16}$

so

$\dfrac{1 + z}{1 + \bar z} = \dfrac{1 + e^{i\theta}}{1 + e^{-i\theta}} = \dfrac{e^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}}  \dfrac{1 + e^{i\theta}}{1 + e^{-i\theta}}$
$= e^{i\theta} \dfrac{1 + e^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta} + 1} = e^{i\theta} = z, \tag{17}$

stipulating of course that $\theta$ is not an odd multiple of $\pi$.